# Trying to display related products using a specific product tag on Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm currently using a script to output related products on a Shopify website I'm managing, but I want to modify this script to grab the current product's "color" tag (E.g. "Color_Jet Black (#1)") and then use this tag to generate related products that also have this tag.

The code below is the code I'm currently using.

```html
<div class="related-products">
    <div class="container-fluid nopadding">
        <div class="row grid">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Variables
      var related = $('.related-products');
      var handle = "{{ product.handle }}";
      var tags = [];
      var appendLocation = $(".related-products .row");
      var relatedProductsList = [];
      var maxOutput = 4
      var count = 0;
    // Get Product Tags
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
      tags.push("{{ tag }}");
}
    {% endfor %}
    // Get Run JSON product tags against this product's tags
    jQuery.getJSON( document.location.origin + "/products.json", function(obj) {
        // Build List
        jQuery.each(obj.products, function(dontcare, product) {
            hasMatch(tags, product);
        });
        // Shuffle List
        shuffle(relatedProductsList);
        // Output List
        jQuery.each(relatedProductsList, function( dontcare, product) {
            if(count < maxOutput) {
                outputMatch(product);
            }
            count++;
        });
    }).complete(function() {
        // Wait for products to load
        $('.product-item img').load(function() {
            var item = $('.product-item');
            setProductItemHeight(item);
        });
    });
    // Checks for a match between product tags and JSON tags
    function hasMatch(tags, product) {
        jQuery.each(tags, function(dontcare, tag) {
            if(jQuery.inArray(tag, product.tags) >= 0 && product.handle != handle) {
                relatedProductsList.push(product);
            }
        });
    }
    // Outputs matches
    function outputMatch (product) {
        // If product has a featured image
        if(product.images[0] != null) {
            // Create Item
            $item = $("<div class='col-md-3'><article class='product-item'><a href=" +
                document.location.origin + "/products/" +
                product.handle +"><div class='image-wrapper'><img class='img-responsive' src='" +
                product.images[0].src + "'></div><div class='product-wrapper prod-caption caption'><h6>" +
                product.title + "</h6></a><p>" + product.variants[0].price + "</p><a class='btn btn-default' href=" + document.location.origin + "/products/" + product.handle +">Buy Now</a></div></article></div>");
            appendLocation.append($item);
        } else if (product.images[0] == null) {
            // Fallback if product object has no images
            appendLocation.append("<div class='col-md-3'><article class='product-item'><a href=" + document.location.origin + "/products/" + product.handle +"><div class='image-wrapper'><img class='img-responsive' src='//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0878/7440/t/2/assets/default.png'></div><div class='product-wrapper prod-caption'><h3>" + product.title + "</h3><p>" + product.tags[0] + "</p><em>" + product.variants[0].price + "</em><br><a class='btn btn-default' href=" + document.location.origin + "/products/" + product.handle +">Buy Now</a></div></article></div>");
        }
    }
    // Randomizes relatedProductsList
    function shuffle(relatedProductsList) {
        for (var n = 0; n < relatedProductsList.length - 1; n++) {
            var k = n + Math.floor(Math.random() * (relatedProductsList.length - n));
            var temp = relatedProductsList[k];
            relatedProductsList[k] = relatedProductsList[n];
            relatedProductsList[n] = temp;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I've attempted to modify the code to grab the current product colour tag, which works, but it doesn't output any products like the original script does. There are plenty of products with this colour tag, so that's not the problem.

The code below is what I used to grab the current product's colour tag, which does work, but nothing it outputted in the DOM.

```html
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Variables
      var related = $('.related-products');
      var handle = "{{ product.handle }}";
      var tags = [];
      var appendLocation = $(".related-products .row");
      var relatedProductsList = [];
      var maxOutput = 4
      var count = 0;
    // Get Product Tags
    {% assign color = "Color_" %}
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
      {% if tag contains color %}
        tags.push("{{ tag }}");
}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Any thoughts / help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a new collection template that outputs json, and apply that template to your json request using the 'view' parameter.

The 'view' param simply allows you to use a different template on the fly to render content. https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/add-view-all-to-collection-pages

Here is an example json liquid template (done off the top of my head - you'll need to check which liquid tags to use):

```
   {% layout none %} // tells shopfify not to render layout template
   {
      "products": [
        {% for product in collection.products %}
    ...
     {
        "id": "{{product.id}}",
        "title": "{{product.title}}",
        "handle": "{{product.handle}}",
        "image" : "{{product.featured_image}}",
        "price" : "{{product.price}}"
    }
    {% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %} ... don't forget the , - it mustn't be on the last entry.
    ....
        {% endfor %}
      ]
    }
```

So when the template is rendered - you'll get a list of products formatted as json. Something like this:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "12234",
      "title": "foo",
      "handle": "bar",
      "image": "blah.jpg",
      "price": "12345"
    },
    {
      "id": "12235",
      "title": "foo1",
      "handle": "bar1",
      "image": "blah1.jpg",
      "price": "12346"
    },
    {
      "id": "12239",
      "title": "foo2",
      "handle": "bar2",
      "image": "blah2.jpg",
      "price": "12375"
    }
  ]
}
```

When making your ajax request, you will need to request the URL with the tags and view. So, if you call your new template json.liquid then you would request:

```
/collections/frontpage/Color_Jet-Black-(#1)?view=json
```

eg:

```
jQuery.getJSON( '/collections/frontpage/Color_Jet-Black-(#1)?view=json", function(obj) {
```

So in this example -  'Color_Jet Black (#1)' is the tag. You should receive only those products in the Frontpage collection that have been tagged with Color_Jet Black (#1). Because we're appending `?view=json` to our request, Shopify will send these products using the json template we created*. You're then free to randomise that json and render it to the page through JavaScript.

- Note in my example I've called the new collection template json.liquid because its being used to render out Json - but you're free to call it whatever you wish. Nb: 'featured_products.liquid'. However, as its being used to output Json it makes sense to call it json.liquid.

Shopify collection urls are in the following format:

```
http://example.com/collections/collectionname/tags?view=CustomTemplate
```

so

```
http://example.com/collections/classic/watches?view=json
```

Would get you all products from the classic collection tagged with watches

```
http://example.com/collections/classic/watches+home?view=json
```

Would get you all products from the classic collection tagged with watches AND home.

You don't need to hardwire the collection into the new json template. You're simple requesting the collection that you need - and telling shopify to render it out as json (using the json template you've created).

Once you have the products in the json format - you can do whatever you like with them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - so say I have 20 different colour tags, I'd need to include each individual tag (formatted as json) within the new template?

Comment: Nope - you'd just append the tag to the url... Shopify will then grab all products from the collection tagged with whatever and render them using that json template you've created. I've updated my answer with clarification on this. If it does the job, please give me a tick ;) thanks